# Export Custom Well regex in Productivity Power Tools

Tags: visual-studio, productivity-power-tools

Is there any way to export the coloring rules for the **Productivity Power Tools**'s component: **Custom Well**?

I have quite a sophisticated configuration and it's always a pain to move it to another computer or to the new version of Visual Studio.

I have tried to export this particular setting using the *Import and Export Settings* of Visual Studio, but cannot locate it there. At he same time, I would prefer not to export/import all the VS settings.

I guess that would be a simple copy paste of one file, but not sure where to look for it.

Copy pasting row by row is the last resort, as for each of the colors you need to manually choose it in the picker (terrible design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research I have found out that the color/regex settings are stored within the registry, under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\DialogPage\Microsoft.CustomDocWell.Options\Colors
```

*(for Visual Studio 2015; for the earlier versions, change 14.0 to the desired version number)*. Those registry settings can be simply exported/imported as any other.

However, the situation differs with the Visual Studio 2017, where the registry structure has been changed. The keys are still there, but it gets a bit more complex to get there. You can read more on the topic here:

https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/29/changing-visual-studio-2017-private-registry-settings/

Answer (score 2):

In VS 2017, you'll have to follow the instructions in

https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2017/06/29/changing-visual-studio-2017-private-registry-settings/

given by mikus, then the Regex will be in the key like:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\_TMPVS_15.0_116e7493\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_116e7493\DialogPage\Microsoft.CustomDocWell.Options\Colors`

But **NOTE** : you may have to add a new regex in visual studio options (Productivity Power Tools -> Custom Document Well -> Color Coding) before this key shows up.